# Maximum likelihood for additive models

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, density-function

Consider the following additive model
\begin{equation*}y=h(x)+v\end{equation*}
where:

- $y\in\mathbb{R}^p$ is the observation
- $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the estimand
- $v$ is noise, distributed according to a PDF $p_v(\cdot)$
- $h:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}^n$ is a map that is invertible

It is trivial to see that the likelihood function for this model is simply
\begin{equation*}
\ell(y,x) = p_v(y-h(x))
\end{equation*}

so that the maximum likelihood estimate of $x$ given $y$ is
\begin{equation*}
\hat{x}_\text{ML}(y) = \arg \max_{s\in\mathbb{R}^n} p_v(y-h(s))
\end{equation*}

**Problem**

I've got the strong suspicion that, in the current simple setting, the maximum likelihood estimate is always
\begin{equation*}
\hat{x}_\text{ML}(y) = h^{-1}(y-v^*)
\end{equation*}
where $v^*$ is the noise mode, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
v^* \triangleq \arg \max_{v \in \mathbb{R}^p} p_v(v)
\end{equation*}
The idea behind my suspect is the following: we are searching for $s$ that, once mapped in the observation space $\mathbb{R}^p$ and combined with $y$, gives the maximum value of the PDF $p_v(\cdot)$. Hence, we are searching for $s$ so that $y-h(s)$ is the mode $v^*$ of $p_v(\cdot)$. Thus, we are searching for the solution of
\begin{equation*}
y-h(s)=v^*
\end{equation*}
which (after changing the name of $s$ to $\hat{x}_{\text{ML}}$) is
\begin{equation*}
\hat{x}_{\text{ML}}=h^{-1}(y-v^*)
\end{equation*}

**Questions**

Is it true my intuition? If no, why? If yes, is it correct my explanation?

Comment: Not sure why you call this "intuition", your derivation shows that it is correct